# New project development & git guidlines and hints

Tags: programming-practices, testing, git, development-process

We are two senior students and we want to develop an app.
Although we dont have experience on using git & github.

Our app will consist of a server handling requests with a mongoDB database. The server will communicate with many different APIs and it will render data to a view.

And now I have some very simple yet important questions to be answered, since we want to follow the best possible practices.

I found lots of stuff on the web but i havent found a concrete answer to those two questions:

**1) How do we test code on the server?**

Each one of us has the local copy of the project writes code commits at the development branch (or his dedicated dev branch(?)) then pull at the server and test the code? Sounds too complicated, since the code must be test often, there must be a better way.

**2) Is it a good practice for each one of us to have its own dev branch or just one?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How do we test code on the server?

   Set up a continuous integration build that runs your tests. Appveyor is good for C#. TravisCI is a good Java option.
2. Is it a good practice for each one of us to have its own dev branch or just one?

   I recommend that you use Git Flow (google it). It short, you'll have many short lived feature branches. Branch from master, implement a feature/bug fix, then submit a pull request for your partner to review, pull local, then merge into master. This keeps branches from drifting away from each other and keeps merge conflicts to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Our code will be in nodejs. I will look for a CI tool for that